# Show images in slider from the string containing text and <img> tag in Angular

Tags: angular, slider

I am working on the blog system in Angular in which I have taken the text editor(ngx-text-editor) in which I am inserting images and the text. I am also saving the images and the text to the database. But when I want to show images in slider and the text in a separate way, I am not able to separate the images from the text.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService} from '../_services';
import { User } from '../_models/user'
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { AuthenticationServiceService } from '../_services';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css']
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[] = [];
  msg: string = null;

  constructor( private authenticationService: AuthenticationServiceService,
    private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBlog();
  }
  private getBlog() {
    this.userService.getBlog().pipe(first()).subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;

      console.log(this.users);
  });
  }
}
```

In this, `console.log(this.users);` I have the images and the text.

```
<p class="new22" style="word-wrap: break-word;" [innerHTML]="user.blog"></p>
```

When I show the data in the html using innerHTML and It is showing the images and text both. I want to show the images in the slider and the text separate. The string contains the  tag and the text. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

So my problem is that, from the database, both  tags and the text are coming. So, How the separate them and show all the images in the slider. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// use this pick all img out
var patt1 = /<img(.*?)>/g;
const m = str.match(patt1);
```

Comment: No, Like when the insert the text and images from the editor. So, Both images and text are going to the database.

Comment: So, That's why I am asking to the separate both, the img tag and the text coming from the database.

Comment: I mean it doesn't make sense, you query data from the database use blog id right? in the API level one API for front-end is ok, but you can use this API call and blog id do two things, one is only querying text, and another is image only.

Comment: Yes, but my question is different. I just want to separate the images and the text from the string coming from the database.

Comment: you mean text and image location are mixed in one string?

Comment: Yes, that's why I have used the innerHTML and I want to show the images in the slider.

Comment: try the latest solution

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: If I want to fetch only src in the images.

Comment: Once again, Thank you for the answer. It has solved my query.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your user.blog text string is something like this:

```
Some length of text followed by <img src="image/url.jpg"> followed by more text.
```

And remembering that a string of text is basically an array of characters, you could write a function that iterates over the text and does the following:

Find the index of `<img`, move the characters from the start of the string to that index into a blogText string, then find the index of `>`, move the characters in the string from the new start (which is now `<img`) to the index of the `>` into a blogImage array, then repeat.

By iterating over the whole string, you can move all the blog text into the blogText string, and wind up with an array of image URLs, and you can display them separately then however you like.